# Dynamic use of variables

Tags: python, dynamic-variables

I have a possibly quick question regarding how to write a program so it can decide how many variables need to be used.

here is code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from os         import system


class TransMsg(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.msgType = ""
        self.canType = ""
        self.ID      = 0
        self.DLC     = 0

        self.tData0  = 0
        self.tData1  = 0
        self.tData2  = 0
        self.tData3  = 0
        self.tData4  = 0
        self.tData5  = 0
        self.tData6  = 0
        self.tData7  = 0
        # extended can only
        self.tData8  = 0
        self.tData9  = 0
        self.tData10 = 0
        self.tData11 = 0
        self.tData12 = 0
        self.tData13 = 0
        self.tData14 = 0
        self.tData15 = 0

        self.count   = 0

def startTrans(msg):

    print( msg.ID, msg.tData0, msg.tData1, msg.tData2, msg.tData3, msg.tData4, msg.tData5, msg.tData6, msg.tData7)

def createMsg():

    msg = TransMsg()

    msg.msgType = raw_input("Please Enter Msg Type\n m = Message String Follows\n r = RTR-Message String Follows\n i = Initialsation String Follows\n")

    msg.canType = raw_input("Please Enter Can Type\n s = Standard Can\n e = Extended Can\n")
    msg.ID      = raw_input("Please enter message ID: ")

    if(msg.canType == 'e'):
        msg.DLC = 16
        extendedString = raw_input("Please enter can message:\n")

        cutter = extendedString.split()
        msg.tData0  = cutter[0]
        msg.tData1  = cutter[1]
        msg.tData2  = cutter[2]
        msg.tData3  = cutter[3]
        msg.tData4  = cutter[4]
        msg.tData5  = cutter[5]
        msg.tData6  = cutter[6]
        msg.tData7  = cutter[7]
        msg.tData8  = cutter[8]
        msg.tData9  = cutter[9]
        msg.tData10 = cutter[10]
        msg.tData11 = cutter[11]
        msg.tData12 = cutter[12]
        msg.tData13 = cutter[13]
        msg.tData14 = cutter[14]
        msg.tData15 = cutter[15]

    elif(msg.canType == 's'):
        msg.DLC = 8
        standardString = raw_input("Please enter can message:\n")

        cutter = standardString.split()
        msg.tData0  = cutter[0]
        msg.tData1  = cutter[1]
        msg.tData2  = cutter[2]
        msg.tData3  = cutter[3]
        msg.tData4  = cutter[4]
        msg.tData5  = cutter[5]
        msg.tData6  = cutter[6]
        msg.tData7  = cutter[7]

    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':

    msg4Trans = createMsg()
    startTrans(msg4Trans)
```

What I need is if the use defines the DLC variable as for example 3 the program only needs to use tData1, 2, and 3. Is this possible within the context of my program?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just using an array?

Comment: Why not just use `cutter` directly instead of creating numbered variables?